# IP Masquerade/Forward on CentOS 5.5

Tags: linux, networking, centos, iptables

I would like to be able to use my web server as a Usenet 'proxy', how would I configure iptables to forward the packets correctly?

My Usenet client will connect to my web server and the web server would make the connection to usenet.

Thanks,

Luke.

Comment: There is nothing special required on iptables's behalf with regards to userspace proxies like leafnode (for nntp) or squid (http, for comparison).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really should be using is an ssh tunnel, not a proxy.  It will do what you want (bounce traffic between your webserver when you want to connect to an nntp server) without installing any special software on your webserver.  Iptables isn't really going to help you here.

http://www.rzg.mpg.de/networkservices/ssh-tunnelling-port-forwarding